# How to POST customised SOAP body in HTTP request ? ( send raw whole XML in the body of a HTTP Request - Android)

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap, wsdl

Trying to make an HTTP SOAP request with a customized request body  (send whole Raw XML)

tried using K2SOAP but want to make a customized  SOAP request

This HTTP SOAP request wants to parse

https://mmauth.com/MIRISYSTEMS/Services/MiriDecoderServices/MiriDecoderService.svc/soap

want to send this XML in request body.

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
   xmlns:dec="http://mirisystemsapps.com/decoderservices/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
   <dec:MiriIDTransaction>
       <!--Optional:-->
       <dec:NumberToVerify>32434-3434-3434-3434</dec:NumberToVerify>
   </dec:MiriIDTransaction>
   </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>
```